# Unable to uninstall alacritty-themes

Tags: pop-os

I've installed alacrytty-themes

[https://dev.to/rajasegar/alacritty-themes-a-cli-tool-to-set-themes-for-alacritty-terminal-144c#:~:text=How%20do%20I%20select%20themes%3F&text=Choose%20the%20theme%20from%20the,and%20press%20Enter%20to%20apply.&text=by%20just%20pressing%20up%20arrow%20key.&text=If%20no%20alacritty](https://dev.to/rajasegar/alacritty-themes-a-cli-tool-to-set-themes-for-alacritty-terminal-144c#:%7E:text=How%20do%20I%20select%20themes%3F&text=Choose%20the%20theme%20from%20the,and%20press%20Enter%20to%20apply.&text=by%20just%20pressing%20up%20arrow%20key.&text=If%20no%20alacritty).

But its not working properly and can't find the way to uninstall it, im o new at linux, im in Pop-Os

Not working properly:
After installing it, and selecting any theme, i can't even write in the terminal, it just split the letters for all the terminal screen, so i can't work with it, so im trying to uninstall it with the basic pop os terminal

Usually i just do `apt remove "package"` but it says can't find the package, so i don't know what to do, sorry im very new at linux,
oh also i've tried to `npm remove alacritty-themes` but the output is `up to date`

Comment: Hello David. Please would you [edit] your question to explain what you mean by "_it's not working properly_". (We aren't with you and can't see what you can see.) What did you expect? What happened? What didn't happen? What error messages or other output did you see? What have you tried to do about it?

Answer (score 2):

For me this finally worked:

```
npm uninstall -g alacritty-themes
```

Don't forget to run it with sudo.